# How to store data to my server from android device?

Tags: android, save, android-edittext

I have written a simple application in android.  It has some edit text boxes and collects input. I want to store the contents of the text boxes on my server.  What's the best way to send the information to the server?

Comment: What type of server is it?  How are you planning on connecting to the server?  Socket connection, http connection, e-mail the information, web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an HTTP server, use a POST request.
This should be useful: [HttpPost reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)
and [a code snippet.](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)